# Spring Web Security logout not working with httpBasic authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using basic authentication to secure an initial REST web service that I'm working on.  Everything **seems** to work okay, except the logout path does not seem to work. It redirects to "/login?logout", as documented, but my user does not seem to actually be logged out. (ie. I can still access page X and not page Y as expected).

Application config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableSwagger
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    @Configuration
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().logout().permitAll().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.GET.toString())).invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN", "USER").and().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that security in general looks to be working.  I can open a new incognito tab and the authentication / security works as expected.

Comment: Do you test with a browser ? Are you sure it is not caching credentials and reuses them "behind your back" ? You should check request/response roundtrips to make sure.

Comment: I don't think that's happening.  I've disabled caching at the moment, and in the logs it seems as if the session was even cleared when I access a "USER" secured path: `2014-08-07 16:58:36.931  INFO 2132 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Thu Aug 07 16:58:36 EDT 2014, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null}]`

Comment: If it matters, logout **does** work when utilized with formLogin()... Am I misunderstanding how the logout path is supposed to work?

Comment: As GPI says, you should check your browser isn't re-sending the credentials automatically, which is common with basic auth and independent of any concept of server-side logout. Also enable debug logging on the server.

Comment: As @LukeTaylor mentioned in general logout doesn't work with basic/digest authentication. Afaik once authenticated the browser keeps sending the headers to the application which effectifly will do a new login once you logged out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot logout from basic http authentication with a logout link.

Please check a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023951/spring-security-unable-to-logout).