# How to connect react frontend with spring boot backend that uses form login for authentication

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Long story short, I have a RESTapi spring boot application that uses form login for session authentication (I know, not the best choice but I need a quick solution for login/logout). I can send the session id with the request to endpoints but to do that I need to log in first and here I have a problem. The form login doesn't work like an API endpoint and requires a form to be set(I don't know how). So can I make the login endpoint accept an HTML request with username and password and respond with a session id to make changes on the react side of things to work? It might be quicker or easier to implement JWT authentication at this point but I don't know.
My config class, just in case

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                auth ->
                    auth.requestMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(
                    lOut ->
                        lOut.invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:5173"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: One easy way is to use HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: Won't be able to logout in that case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023951/spring-security-unable-to-logout